# ! Help Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ´ (U+B4)

Tags: errors, symbols, unicode

please help me.
when running my latex code, this error is appeared:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ´ (U+B4)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you search for "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character" on this site, you'll obtain dozens and dozens of hits, along with answers that provide various types of solutions.

Comment: either your document is not in UTF-8 in which case you should get your editor to re-save it in that encoding, or you have a character U+00B4 which is an acute accent  (´) in which case you should type that another way, depending on what you intended.

Comment: Do make sure your TeX distribution is fully up to date. For sure, when I compile the test document `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} ´ \end{document}`, I encounter no problems under either pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX. (My TeX distribution is MacTeX2019, LaTeX format `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02>` with `L3 programming layer <2020-01-31>`.) Note that it's no longer necessary to load the `inputenc` package under pdfLaTeX *unless* your input file's encoding is *not* UTF8.